# Given problem to be solved in O(n) , but solution using sort() is accepted

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

I'm a beginner and was confused as to why , if we are given to solve a problem in `O(n)` , and I'm using `sort()` (`O(nlogn)`) the platform is accepting the answer , isn't `O(nlogn) > O(n)`?

Comment: `log(n)` might easily be considered as `k` (constant) as it grows very slowly for some input size. See [that graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28n+log%28n%29%29+and+plot+%2810+n%29+from+1+to+10000)

Comment: Yes, but those are not time measurements. `0.0000001*n*log(n)` is `O(n*log(n))`, and `1000000000000*n` is `O(n)`, and n must grow very large for the former to grow larger than the latter. Your "platform" isn't testing with large enough inputs to notice.

Comment: What do you mean by "the platform is accepting the answer"?

Answer (score 2):

> isn't O(nlogn) > O(n) ?

Yes. If you used `std::sort` with input of length n, then you didn't solve the problem in O(n).